# Questions during setup in Docker build freeze the build process

Tags: docker, ubuntu, input, build, command

**Issue**

I am trying to install some drivers on a Docker image. During the procedure, one of the installation asks me for some input from command line. This obviously freezes the procedure. How can I solve this?

**How to reproduce the issue**

Start a shell in the base image:  `docker run -it nvcr.io/nvidia/deepstream:6.0-triton`

Run the following commands:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

# Set some variables to download the proper header modules
export VERSION="2.83.18%2Brev1.dev"
export BALENA_MACHINE_NAME="genericx86-64-ext"

# Set variables for the Yocto version of the OS
export YOCTO_VERSION=5.10.43
export YOCTO_KERNEL=${YOCTO_VERSION}-yocto-standard

# Set variables to download proper NVIDIA driver
export NVIDIA_DRIVER_VERSION=470.86
export NVIDIA_DRIVER=NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-${NVIDIA_DRIVER_VERSION}

# Install some prereqs
apt install -y git wget unzip build-essential libelf-dev bc libssl-dev bison flex software-properties-common

mkdir -p /usr/src/kernel_source
cd /usr/src/kernel_source

# Causes a pipeline to produce a failure return code if any command errors.
# Normally, pipelines only return a failure if the last command errors.
#SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-o", "pipefail", "-c"]

# Download the kernel source then prepare kernel source to build a module.
curl -fsSL "https://files.balena-cloud.com/images/${BALENA_MACHINE_NAME}/${VERSION}/kernel_source.tar.gz" \
    | tar xz --strip-components=2 && \
    make -C build modules_prepare -j"$(nproc)"
```

The last command will have the following output, and then it will freeze waiting for user input:

```
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/kernel_source/build'
  SYNC    include/config/auto.conf.cmd
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/conf.o
  LEX     scripts/kconfig/lexer.lex.c
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/expr.o
  YACC    scripts/kconfig/parser.tab.[ch]
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/symbol.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/preprocess.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/util.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/confdata.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/lexer.lex.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/parser.tab.o
  HOSTLD  scripts/kconfig/conf
*
* Restart config...
*
*
* BPF based packet filtering framework (BPFILTER)
*
BPF based packet filtering framework (BPFILTER) (BPFILTER) [Y/n/?] y
  bpfilter kernel module with user mode helper (BPFILTER_UMH) [M/n/y/?] (NEW)
```

**Notes**

- It seems that `export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` is not doing the job.
- Looking at `make` options there doesn't seem to be an option to skip the question, but I guess I am wrong. How can I fix this?

Comment: No matter what else, you won't be able to install a Linux kernel module from inside a Docker container; this _must_ be done on the host, and it needs to be repeated whenever the host's kernel is upgraded.  This doesn't seem like the sort of programming-related question that's on-topic for Stack Overflow, and somewhere like [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com) or [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com) might be more appropriate.

Comment: I think you should be able to do it, as I was trying to replicate a Balena.io official example https://github.com/balena-io-examples/nvidia-x86/blob/master/cuda/Dockerfile